# Swift: Pixelated Text In UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, uilabel

I am changing the `UILabel`'s color, and text in a reusable prototype cell in my `UITableView`.  For one specific cell (one where I am getting information from a database) the text becomes distorted and pixelated.  I suspect that this has something to do with the table cell being loaded multiple times.  Here's my code that calls the cell to be displayed:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 
{
    let event = events[indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "eventCell") as! eventCell
    cell.setEvent(event: event)
    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    //This code right here is mostly just for rounded edges but maybe the issue is here?

    let verticalPadding: CGFloat = 15
    let maskLayer = CALayer()
    maskLayer.cornerRadius = 10
    maskLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    maskLayer.frame = CGRect(x: cell.bounds.origin.x, y: cell.bounds.origin.y, width: cell.bounds.width, height: cell.bounds.height).insetBy(dx: 0, dy: verticalPadding/2)
    cell.layer.mask = maskLayer
}
```

and then here is the code in the `eventCell` class, which houses all the directions for how to display the code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
// and a few more outlets
func setEvent(event: event) {
    dateLabel.text = event.date
    titleLabel.text = event.title
    //and a few more of those^^ you get the idea
    db.collection("events").document(event.docID).getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            let chairArray = document.data()!["chairPeople"] as! Array<String>
            for person in chairArray {
                if (person == event.email) {
                    self.eventInfoButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 50, alpha: 1)
                    self.dateLabel.textColor = UIColor(white: 50, alpha: 1)
                    self.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor(white: 50, alpha: 1)
                    self.descriptionLabel.textColor = UIColor(white: 50, alpha: 1)
                    self.eventInfoButton.setTitle("Chairsperson tools", for: .normal)
                    self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.26, green:0.55, blue:0.79, alpha:1.0)

                }
            }
        }
    }
 // This code right here ^^ grabs from the database and modifies the look if a conditon is met.  If the condition is met, the text becomes distorted
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the problem.  As you see the `Cells` which are grey have no issue but the blue one is pixilated (that's the one that's getting work done based on information from the database).
[image: Screenshot of the blue pixilated UITableViewCell]